# Apply "Child of"-Constraint?

Tags: constraints

I have added a cane to the hand bone of a rigged model by using a "Child of"-Constraint and now i want to make the location and rotation of the contraint permanent, so i can parent it to the rig. I tried to apply "Visual Transform" but then the cane moves to an entirely different place.

[image]

Comment: Why would you parent it to the rig, if you have a thing that works now?

Comment: Apply visual transform and delete the constraint then parent it.

Comment: Why parent it to the rig? Because i want to export to a different format, that doesnt support constraints.
@Jerryno: applying Visual Transform causes the cane to move away from the bone.

Comment: and? delete the constraint and it will move back. It's supposed to move away from the bone. If it doesn't return back, there are other things effecting the cane (like drivers or other constraints)